# What is the relation between entropy and pressure in strict thermodynamic terms?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, entropy

I read on the net that it is a general consensus that entropy in a system decreases as pressure increases and vice versa.

1. How can one reach such conclusion using the characteristic equation in terms of entropy?
   $$dS=(1/T)dU+(p/T)dV-(μ_B/T)dn_b$$
   and lets assume there is no change in molecular mass, so we use only the first 2 clauses.
2. Can we prove, without making any other assumptions like ideal gas or other simplifications, that the strict thermodynamic term $(\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial p})_T$ is, as the general consensus is, negative, thus increasing pressure, decreases entropy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a Maxwell relation we known that:
$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}\right)_{T}=-\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_{p}$$
For gases and most liquids, $\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_{p}>0$, so indeed the entropy decreases as pressure increases.

**Derivation:** Starting with the Gibbs free energy relation: 
$$dG=VdP-SdT$$

$$dG=\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial P}\right)_{T}dP+\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial T}\right)_{P}dT$$

we find the thermodynamic definition of volume and entropy:
$$V=\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial P}\right)_{T}\quad S=-\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial T}\right)_{P}$$

since we know from calculus:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial P}\right)_{T}=\frac{\partial}{\partial P}\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial T}\right)_{P}
 $$

It follows that:
$$\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_{P}=-\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_{T}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer nioojie. Unfortunately I explicitly stated in my question, whether this applies without the help of simplifications, which certainly do not apply for liquids, metal alloys, polymer blends e.t.c.

Comment: @Kaizokugari I think for most gases and liquids you will find that the volume expands with increasing temperature at constant pressure. Atleast for part of the phase diagram of the substance. Solids are not applicable in this case, i believe.

Comment: Yes, although some polymers and even water under 4 deg C exhibit negative volume expansion, I believe you might be right.

Comment: @Kaizokugari when deviations from thermodynamic ideality come into play then indeed it may be a different case. However, in general it is true that substances tend to increase in volume with increasing temperature, so like you say the general consensus is that entropy decreases with increasing pressure. Since my answer in fact does not contain the simplification of an ideal gas but simply the requirement $\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_{S}>0$ (which happens to be the case for ideal gases but also for liquids) please reconsider accepting my answer.

Comment: It is not a deviation actually, there can't be a thermodynamic deviation or else the axioms would crumble. It is something that doesn't happen in many materials, but nothing non ideal happens in NVE. Nevertheless, ignoring the derivation, in which something happens and your constant parameters are V&S instead of T&P, jordix's answer ignores any requirements, so I guess it's only fair to leave him the "accepted answer" tick, at least until his proof is proven faulty. rmhleo has objected in jordix's answer, so please feel free to contribute, so we can unanimously get a correct answer.

Comment: @Kaizokugari: thx for pointing out the mistake in the derivation, it has been fixed. With deviation I meant deviation from ideal behaviour; water below 4 deg C is a prime example of non-ideal behaviour due to the presence of hydrogen bonds.

Answer (score 0):

You are right: further specifications i.e. constraints have to be provided in order to provide such affirmation.

Your expression of entropy as a thermodynamical potential in terms of internal energy, volume and particle number, does not provide a unique relation between two thermodynamic variables. Instead it provides a dependence of the entropy, as the main function describing a system, as a function of the parameters which are free and independent of each other in this case.

Choosing for example, the ideal gas as the system, then you are constraining further the system to the ideal gas relation $PV=nRT$, which can in turn give the desired relation as was shown already in the other answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer mhieo. Of course, further mathematical expansions like the Maxwell equations, Legendre transformations (which of course are essential to reach Gibbs free energy) or even algorithms to find thermodynamic relations like A.N. Shaw's Jacobians, would still apply to the solution without further thermodynamic constraints. Certainly, even if we indeed added some further constraints, it would be important to let them hold a plausible result at the end, because e.g. the ideal gas law pretty much nerfs any viable conclusion for real life applications.

Comment: @Kaizokugari I did not fully understand your comment. Anyway, the short answer is: no, is not possible to say this holds for all systems that only are required to abide to your assumptions.

Comment: I meant you can do whatever you want mathematically in the given characteristic equation. Anyways, feel free to check jordix's answer in case I'm missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with

$dU = T\,dS - p\,dV$.

The enthalpy is defined as

$H = U + p\,V$,

so

$dH = dU + p\,dV + V\,dp = T\,dS + V\,dp$.

Remember that the enthalpy is the heat at constant pressure, and that

$dH = C_p\,dT$.

This is used to define the heat capacity at constant pressure $C_p$.

From these last equations,

$\displaystyle dS = \frac{C_p}{T} dT - \frac{V}{T}dp$,

and from the definition of exact differential,

$\displaystyle dS = \left.\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_p dT +
                    \left.\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}\right)_T dp$.

Therefore,

$\displaystyle \left.\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}\right)_T = -\frac{V}{T}$,

which is always negative because both $V$ and $T$ can only be positive.

Notice that you don't need to assume any particular equation of state for the gas, i.e. you don't need to assume that the gas is ideal.

Comment: @Kaizokugari this answer does not answer the question as stated and has mistakes. First it implicitly assumes fixed particle number (no dependence on n) contrary to question. Second, implicitly assumes ideal gas relation $dH=CpdT$. Third, expression $dS=\frac{C_p}{T}dT-\frac{V}{T}dp$ is not an exact differential: this is contrary to $dS=dU/T+p/TdV$

Comment: The meaning of the last expression is that all thermodynamic systems for which entropy is the th. potential (function whose values determine fully their state) it can be only expressed as exat diferential on diferences of $dU,dV$ and $dn$ if we are to consider it too. You cannot express any thermodynamic variable as an exact differential of any other number of whichever other thermodynamic variables you choose, because you are basically changing the laws of physics.

Comment: The meaning of the last expression is that all thermodynamic systems for which entropy is the thermodynamic potential (function whose values determine fully their state) S can only be expressed as an exact differential on exact differences $dU,dV$ and $dn$ if we are to consider it too. You cannot express any thermodynamic variable as an exact differential of any other number of whichever other thermodynamic variables you choose, because you are basically changing the laws of physics. In other words, for example $dU=TdS+pdV$ is the only way, $dU=(dU/dT)_pdT+(dU/dp)_Tdp$ is not an exact differen

Comment: @rmhleo I don't understand the vocabulary that you are using, since you seem to imply that some expressions of $dS$ are exact differentials and others are not. This is wrong. It's not the expression that makes $dS$ an exact differential or not. It's actually $dS$ that is an exact differential, no matter how you express it in terms of other magnitudes.

Comment: @mhleo Firstly, I already assumed fixed particle number ("no change in molecular mass"). Secondly, to my knowledge, $C_p=(ΔΗ/ΔΤ)$ is valid for any system, directly from the definition of $C_p$. If it does indeed stand only for ideal gases, please cite it, as I cannot find any reference online. Thirdly, you can describe any thermodynamic term, through Legendre transformations (this is, for any variable combination you like). This is how we create new mathematical expressions for energies, like Enthalpy (which is indeed contained in the mentioned expression in $C_p$) or Helmotz energy.

Comment: @jordix I will be happy to direct you to sources covering any of the terms you would like to clarify, I apologize for this. I think we can direct the discussion by parts so we can establish the point on which we agree and those on which we don't. I think we will all agree that a thermodynamic system in general can be described with a set of thermodynamic variables, say U,S,V,p,T for our purposes. So these variables offer the full description of the system. Now, are they all independent? No, their information  is interdependent, and $dU=TdS+pdV$ tells you can describe it fully by setting $S,V$

Comment: @jordix, continuing, you have thus determined that you can describe a system that complies with $dU=TdS-pdV$ (all thermodynamic systems) with only $S,V$ values. This also implies that all other quantities in this case depend on $S,V$: $T=T(S,V),p=p(S,V)$. So if you want to describe the system in terms of, lets say $T,V$, this changes the role of $U$ which now is not the fundamental function, because it can have the same value for different states of the system. This is the reason why you need to use a different fundamental function to fully characterize the system.

Comment: And the fundamental function or thermodynamic potential in this case is $F=U-TS$ which we are finding through a Legendre transformation. And its differential form $dF=dU-TdS-SdT=-SdT-pdV$ now expressed as a linear dependence on $T,V$ is the correct one. Now, although you can still say in this case $dU=TdS-pdV$ it has a different meaning now because you established the fundamental variables to be $T,V$ and now since $S=S(T,V)$ implies that $dS=dS(T,V)$. So the relation that held before $T=(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S})_V$ does not hold anymore, at least without any further assumptions.

Comment: @Kaizokugari I understand now, but please bare in mind that "no change in molecular mass" sounds more like no change in the mass of molecules rather than no change in  the mass of the system which would convey better the idea of no change in the number of molecules. As for the $C_p$ expression I am wrong indeed this is not  the case for ideal gas. The general expression is $c_p=(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T})_P$. But bare in mind that $dH=CpdT$ is not at all the same, and in general does not hold. Finally, for comments on your last sentence please check the extra comments I added to jordix.

Comment: @rmhleo Indeed $\displaystyle dS = \frac{C_p}{T} dT - \frac{V}{T}dp$ seems not to be an exact differential ; application of Euler's condition of $ \dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial N}{\partial x}$ for an $Mdx+Ndy$ relationship to be an exact differential does not apply. This gets really peculliar. Is nlooije's $\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_{p}>0$ condition really the only way it works then?

Comment: I am not sure, I will think about it and search, and whatever I find I can extend my answer (comments are too short). But my guess is that there are more than one situation in which you could have this. The bottom line is: extra constraints are needed.

Comment: @rmhleo You say that $dS$ is an exact differential only if it is expressed in terms of some variables, but not if it is expressed in terms of $C_p$, $dT$, $T$ and $V$ (sic). This is wrong: $dS$ is always an exact differential, and of course every expression for $dS$ is an exact differential and satisfies the rule of the crossed partial derivatives. If you express it in terms of $dT$ and $dp$ you will find a relation (which you can consider a Maxwell relation, if you want). This relation is valid in general, but if you check the derivatives, you will see it works for an ideal gas, for example.

Comment: @jordix this is not the case in thermodynamics: you cannot say any differentiation of one variable in terms of any other two will be an exact differential. Your expression is like saying that $dV = T/p dS - dU/p$ from $dU = TdS - pdV$, and is wrong. So it holds for an ideal gas, you are right. Does that mean you need a counter example? You can verify it does not hold for a Van der Waals gas.